# Проблемы кодировки

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема, не могу решить. Вытаскиваю из базы текст и циклом проставляю после каждой буквы любой имаго или букву. На выходе получается текст наполненный кракозябрами. При этом и база и кодировка Yii2 и в phpinfo() стоит utf-8. Правда Файлы сохранены в ASCII и символы вбитые в коде через mb_detect_encoding выдают ASCII. Может ли проблема быть именно в том что кодировка файлов в ascii. И если может то почему, ведь ascii же как бы почти utf-8. И как решить такую проблему без переделываемся кодировки файлов?

Comment: Не кода, не текста, ничего, набор слов.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно знать как и откуда база была заполнена.

Определи точно свою кодировку и примени это [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "CP1251");
```